# Change buffer before async call returns its result

Tags: asynchronous, emacs, buffer

I have the following function that creates a new buffer and calls a compilation watcher asynchronously in it. This means that every time I save the file I'm working on the watcher will compile it and returns the result:

```lisp
(defun dune-watch (exe)
  "Will call dune build -w EXE on an async process."
  (interactive "sBuild name: ")
  (let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "Dune watch")))
    (with-current-buffer buffer (compilation-minor-mode t))
    (projectile-run-async-shell-command-in-root (concat "dune build -w " exe) buffer)
    ;; Make this process non blocking for killing
    (set-process-query-on-exit-flag (get-buffer-process buffer) nil)
    (display-buffer buffer '((display-buffer-below-selected display-buffer-at-bottom)
                             (inhibit-same-window . t)
                             (window-height . 0.2)))))
```

A normal run will look like this (lines preceded by `#` were added by me):

```
Success, waiting for filesystem changes...

# save file

********** NEW BUILD (src/ident.ml changed) **********

File "src/ident.ml", line 46, characters 46-48:
46 | let compare t1 t2 = String.compare t1.name t2.na
                                                   ^^
Error: Unbound record field na
Had errors, waiting for filesystem changes...

# save file

********** NEW BUILD (src/ident.ml changed) **********

Success, waiting for filesystem changes...
```

Now, this doesn't suit me really well because it messes up with the compilation buffer regexp alist so I tried erasing the buffer any time I save a file:

```lisp
(defun erase-and-fill-buffer (buffer)
  "Blahblah BUFFER."
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (erase-buffer)
    (insert "Dune watch buffer")
    ))

(defun dune-watch (exe)
  "Will call dune build -w EXE on an async process."
  (interactive "sBuild name: ")
  (let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "Dune watch")))
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook (lambda () (erase-and-fill-buffer buffer)))
    (with-current-buffer buffer (compilation-minor-mode t))
    (projectile-run-async-shell-command-in-root (concat "dune build -w " exe) buffer)
    ;; Make this process non blocking for killing
    (set-process-query-on-exit-flag (get-buffer-process buffer) nil)
    (display-buffer buffer '((display-buffer-below-selected display-buffer-at-bottom)
                             (inhibit-same-window . t)
                             (window-height . 0.2)))))
```

But to my surprise, this doesn't work. Remember that `dune build -w` is only executed when a file is saved and I'm hooking to `before-save-hook`. Here's the whole content of the buffer:

- after first save:

  ```
  Success, waiting for filesystem changes...
  Dune watch buffer
  ```
- after second save

  ```
  ********** NEW BUILD (src/ident.ml changed) **********

  File "src/ident.ml", line 46, characters 46-47:
  46 | let compare t1 t2 = String.compare t1.name t2.n
                                                   ^
  Error: Unbound record field n
  Had errors, waiting for filesystem changes...
  Dune watch buffer
  ```

My insert comes after the asynchronous call even though this call should have happened after the file was saved. I tried to output the result of the asynchronous call in another buffer but I encounter the same problem since I don't know how to copy only the last displayed message and not the whole buffer without erasing it.